# Not Getting Updated Selected Value from a Dynamically made DropDown

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm not getting value from a City-list DropDown which is Dynamically made. I'm first making required data Jason using AJAX in a Script and then sending it to another page to create Dynamic DropDown. In this City-list is my dynamic made dropdown which depends on the selection of Provincedown Dropdown but the problem comes when I select any option from City-list dropdown which is Dynamically build using ajax than its very first value comes as a selection no matter what option you have selected. Any Suggestions.Here is my Code of provincedown and City-list Dropdown.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="City_Name" value="<?= $City_Name; ?>" >
 <input type="hidden" name="Province_Name" value="<?= $ProvinceName ?>" >
 <label>Province: </label><br>
 <select name="Provincedown" id="ProvinceDropDown"  class="form-control" onChange="getState(this.value);">
 <option value="SelectProvince" <?=$ProvinceName == 'SelectProvince' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?> > Please Select </option>
 <option value="Sindh" <?=$ProvinceName == 'Sindh' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>> Sindh </option>
 </select>
 <label>City:</label><br/>
 <select name="City-list" id="City-list" >
 <option value="SelectCity" >Select City</option>
 </select>
```

**making data jason using AJAX whom code is**

```
 <body onload="getState()"> 
 <script>
 function getState(val) {
 //var cityName = $City_Name;
  var City_Name = $("input[name='City_Name']").val();

 var Province_id = $("input[name='Province_Name']").val();  
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "fetch_state_Edit.php",
 data:{country_id : val, City_Name : City_Name,Province_id : Province_id},
 success: function(data){
    $("#City-list").html(data);
 }
 });
 }
 </script>
```

**fetch_state_Edit.php**

```
 <?php
 if(!empty($_POST["Province_id"])) {
 $country_id =$_POST['country_id'];
 if($country_id=="SelectProvince" || $country_id=="")
 $country_id=$_POST['Province_id'];
 $City_Name=$_POST['City_Name'];
 $results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT City_Name FROM location WHERE Province = '$country_id' ");
 ?>
 <option value="SelectCity">Select City</option>
 <?php
 foreach($results as $state) {
 ?>
  <option value="<?php $state["City_Name"]; ?>" <?=$state["City_Name"] == $City_Name ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>><?php echo $state["City_Name"];</option>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Comment: `<option value="<?php $state["City_Name"]; ?>"` Not sure if it's your only problem, but you definitely need an `echo` in there.

Comment: @PatrickQ Can this solve my problem ???

Comment: @PatrickQ thanks Alot you save my day man (((: uff

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in fetch_state_Edit.php file Just put echo before $state["City_Name"];

```
     <?php
     if(!empty($_POST["Province_id"])) {
     $country_id =$_POST['country_id'];
     if($country_id=="SelectProvince" || $country_id=="")
     $country_id=$_POST['Province_id'];
     $City_Name=$_POST['City_Name'];
     $results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT City_Name FROM location WHERE Province = '$country_id' ");
     ?>
     <option value="SelectCity">Select City</option>
     <?php
     foreach($results as $state) {
     ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $state["City_Name"]; ?>" <?=$state["City_Name"] == $City_Name ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>><?php echo $state["City_Name"];          </option>
    <?php
     }
     }
     ?>
```